# Output string to cmd displayed right but not recognised as command

Tags: c++, cmd

I'm using WriteConsoleOutputCharacter to write a string on the console.My goal is that if that string is a command then i could execute it normally (by pressing enter).However the result is that although i have the command showing up alright, it cannot be executed.When i hit enter the cmd just ignores it and shows a new line as if the previous is empty.  Is there any way to force the cmd see it as a command ?
Here is what i've done:

```
HANDLE hStdout;
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi; 

void dir( HANDLE hConsole )
{
    DWORD cCharsWritten;
    COORD  crCurr;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdout, &csbi);
    crCurr = csbi.dwCursorPosition;

    std::wstring ss;
    ss=std::wstring(L"dir ");

    SetConsoleCursorPosition( hConsole, crCurr );

    if( !WriteConsoleOutputCharacter( hConsole,         
                                ss.c_str(),     
                                (DWORD)ss.length(),       
                                crCurr,     
                                &cCharsWritten ))
    {
      return;
    }

}

int main( void )
{
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdout, &csbi);
    dir(hStdout);
    return 0;
}
```

The result i'm getting was

```
C:\Users\..\Desktop>prog.exe
dir
```

which is not ok,since i'm missing the "C:\Users..\Desktop>" part that prompts for new command.
So i thought i'd execute me programm using the start /B method to get the prompt back.Indeed  the output now is

```
C:\Users\..\Desktop>start /B prog.exe
C:\Users\..\Desktop>dir
```

but the dir command is not executed when i hit enter,i just get a new line.

```
C:\Users\..\Desktop>start /B prog.exe
C:\Users\..\Desktop>dir
C:\Users\..\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` is a function that writes to the console. It does not feed it into the input buffer of the console application itself. Do to that, you will need to feed it into the `stdin` on the cmd.exe, not draw it on the output of the console. The way to do that is to open the console with for example `_popen` (or some lower level `CreateProcess` and then redirect the I/O to a pipe). Then you feed the commands you want to execute into the pipe. cmd.exe will then think that it's been typed in, and execute the command.